# microservices URL redirection to another URL (VIP)

Tags: java, nginx, load-balancing, microservices, virtual-ip-address

I am breaking one monolithic service into different small microservices where each microservice will be hosting different APIs and running on different machines.

I want the old endpoint(VIP) of my monolithic service to be same, so that my clients don't have to change anything at their end and based on the API request VIP is able to redirect the request to appropriate microservice service VIP. Is there anyway I am able to achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Write your microservices, then rewrite your monolithic service to call your microservices.